# Get text size in TextView the same as that of text in two adjoining buttons (Android)

Tags: android, button, textview

I have a simple layout in Android where I have a LinearLayout with vertical orientation. I add a TextView with a normal sentence with a blank.
Then I have a couple of buttons which correspond to two possible values for the blank in the sentence.
The text size in the button is much bigger than that in the sentence. 
Is there a way to specify the text in the TextView to have the same size as that in the Button's?
The code is as follows

```
<TextView android:id="@+id/sentence"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:text="Today we meet __  to give you some good news."
      android:padding="8dp"
       />
<LinearLayout 
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal"

android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal">


<Button android:id="@+id/leftAnswerButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="with you"
        />
<Button android:id="@+id/rightAnswerButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="with each other"
    />



</LinearLayout>

<Button android:id="@+id/nextButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Next"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    />



<LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="fill_parent"
          android:orientation="horizontal"
          >

<TextView android:id="@+id/progres"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:text="Question: 3/10"
          android:paddingRight="4dp"
          android:paddingLeft="12dp"
          android:layout_gravity="bottom|left"
          android:paddingBottom="4dp"
          />
          <LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:gravity="right" android:layout_gravity="bottom">
<TextView android:id="@+id/encerts"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:text="Correct: 2/9"
          android:paddingRight="12dp"
          android:paddingLeft="4dp"
          android:layout_gravity="right"
          android:paddingBottom="4dp"
          />
</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use-

```
android:textSize="18sp"
```

With the help of this code you able to set text size. Use same size in `buttons` and `textview`.

Comment: set integer value according to your requirement.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply specify the text size attribute for the `textview` and `button` as below:

```
android:textSize="30sp"
```

Comment: Friend whenever you give answer then try to provide some different answer so that user try other alternatives and learn something new. +1     for your answer.

Comment: Simultaneous answers? Yes the answer is the same in both cases. And it works.